# How to filter NSArray from section using predicate

Tags: objective-c

I want to filter NSArray from section, but my result is empty. 
Please take a look at my code below.

I have my Animal class.

```
@interface Animal : NSObject
{
   int _id;
   NSString *_name;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

- (id) initWithUniquedId:(int)strId strName:(NSString *)strName;
```

// implement Animal.m

```
- (id) initWithUniquedId:(int)strId strName:(NSString *)strName{
   if(self = [super init]){
      self.id = strId;
      self.name = strName;
   }
   return self;
}
```

This is the function I get data from database;

```
- (NSArray *)getAnimalInfo : (NSString *) argType{
      // [...] Open database
      NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM animal WHERE type = %@ ", argType];
      sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;

      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8Sring], -1, &sqlstmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
         while(sqlite3_step(sqlstmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
            int tmpId = sqlite3_column_int (sqlstmt, 0);
            char *tmpName = (char *) sqlite3_column_text (sqlstmt, 1);

            // Create object from class animal
            Animal *am = [[Animal alloc] initWithUniquedId: tmpId strName: tmpName];
            [data addObject: am];
         }
         sqlite3_finalize(sqlstmt);
      }
      // close database
      return data;
}
```

In my viewcontroller I have implemented code to get all animal information.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  myData = [[NSArray alloc] init];

  // There are many type of animal, so I need make it as section;
  // This is what I show my tableview by section something like: poultry, dog, fish....

  [myData addObject: [self getAnimalInfo: "poultry"]]; //type: poultry will contain many row
  [myData addObject: [self getAnimalInfo: "dog"]]; //type: dog will contain many row
  [myData addObject: [self getAnimalInfo: "fish"]]; //type: fish will contain many row
}
```

They are working good and display properly.

And what I want is searching those information by name from myData array.
Look at the code what I am using is filterArrayUsingPredicate but there is no result.
I wonder on how to search from myData array?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS [cd] %@", myStringSearch];
self.myFilterAnimal = [myData filterArrayUsingPredicate:predicate;
NSLog(@"%@", self.myFilterAnimal];
```

// But there is no result.

Sorry for my bad English.
Thank for reading.

Comment: how about using 'name' without SELF?

Comment: I have tried all, but still result is empty !!

Comment: are you using the correct search string ? Is there any object in array `myData` with `name` same as that of your `myStringSearch` ?